# ReactJS checkable list issue

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I'm trying to create React component that contains a long list (~500 items) with checkboxes opposite each item. It should toggle checked state of each item and toggle checked state of all items in the list. I implemented that component, as I see that. But my solution has low performance and some time lag when I toggle checkbox. When I integrated that in page, it work slower than this jsFiddle example.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaxxreal/69z2wepo/14552/)

What I'm doing wrong? Should I choose another way to work with items data?

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    var db = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = 100; i < l; i++) {
      db.push({
        name: Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5),
        value: i
      });
    }
    return {
      db: db
    };
  },
  checkAll: function (ev) {
    var items = this.state.db.slice();
    items.forEach(function (v) {
      v.checked = ev.target.checked;
    });
    this.setState({db: items});

  },
  handleCheck: function (ev) {
    debugger;
    var id = ev.target.dataset.id;
    var items = this.state.db.slice();
    var item = items.filter(function (v) {
      return v.value == id;
    })[0];
    item.checked = ev.target.checked;
    console.log(items.filter(function (v) {
      return v.checked;
    }));
    this.state({db: items});

  },
  render: function () {
    return <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck} id="check-all"/>
            <label htmlFor="check-all">Check all</label>
          </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> {
          this.state.db.map(function (v, i) {
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{v.name}</td>
                  <td>{v.value}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input id={'item-'+i} type="checkbox"
                           data-id={i}
                           onChange={this.handleCheck}
                           checked={v.checked}/>
                    <label htmlFor={'item-'+i}>Check this</label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            );
          }.bind(this))
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>;
  }
});
```

**SOLUTION**

I have many cells in my table with complex hierarchy. When I toggle checkbox value, all cells rerendered, including ones with unchanged values, that causes huge time lag. I splited up my component to some small components with `shouldComponentUpdate` callbacks and that works fine. Thanks all for help!

Comment: when you call setState you force a render. This is probably what is slowing down you component.
As far as I can see you don't need handleCheck at all, as the checkbox does not need to re-render.

Comment: @AndreasMøller I was thinking about avoid onChange callback, but how I can reflect current state of UI to component model without setState method?

Comment: No I am wrong, the change handler is necessary for it to be a controlled component.

Comment: you could create a checkbox component that has and internal state, so you can update just a single checkbox instead of the whole list.

Comment: But if I create a checkbox component, I have the same problem - reflect one state to parent component model via props or actions, and that initiate setState again. Its vicious circle!

Comment: yes you are correct, I will fork the fiddle, and see if I can get you a better answer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some improvements to your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfbodh90/1/

What I've changed:

In the event handler, you can get the item by index, speeding up lookup time a lot:

```
handleCheck: function (id) {
  var items = this.state.db;
  var item = items[id]
  item.checked = ev.target.checked;
  this.setState({db: items});
}
```

Another thing: when creating the checkbox, you can pass the index parameter directly, using `bind`:

```
<input id={'item-'+i} type="checkbox"
                      onChange={this.handleCheck.bind(this, i)}
                      checked={v.checked}/>
<label htmlFor={'item-'+i}>Check this</label>
```

I've also removed the `slice` calls which are not necessary in the example given.

I've increased the number of items on the JSFiddle above just for testing. Now when you check/uncheck an specific checkbox, it's really fast.

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you very much! Your idea guide me to the right way!